# OSX Lion freeze after sleep

Tags: macos, ssd, sleep-wake, bug

Sometimes, after I wake up my MBP from sleep I get the screen shown in picture. Once I click somewhere in the middle of the screen I get the log in window. When I log in all the windows/apps that were open before sleep are closed. This doesn't happen always but it happens quite often. Any suggestions? Has anyone had same problem ? This started happening after installing SSD. (Crucial M4)[image]

Comment: My colleague sees the same behavior returning from sleep on his MB Air. It's not intermittent behaviour though. Happens always when returning from sleep.

Comment: @IanC. the solution suggested bellow seems to work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've experienced this [as well](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/43192/13414). The error is actually related to the settings of **diplay sleep** and **computer sleep**:

> In **System Preferences > Energy Saver** the timers for *display sleep* and *computer sleep* must be *greater* than the *time of auto logout after inactivity* in **System Preferences > Security & Privacy**.

Comment: It looks like the issue is fixed. Although I think apple should do something about this. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Before I saw this answer, I turned off automatic logout and haven't seen the problem since.